# Insert to Oracle table in a loop

Tags: bash, shell-script, sql, oracle-database

Requirement: In one server in a directory multiple files are present. I need to read the file names and populate into a Oracle table.

I have written the script like this, but its not working:

```
#!/bin/bash
names = find  /home/devuser -name 'BI*'
sqlplus -s  schema_name/passwd << EOF
for name in {names[@]}
do
insert into table1(file_name,status) values('$name','N'); done commit; exit
```

It's trowing `DO INVALID IDENTIFIER`.

Answer (score 3):

```
for VARIABLE in 1 2 3 4 5 .. N
do
    command1
    command2
    commandN
done <<anything given here is taken as variable>>
```

This is the basic syntax and after `done`, commit should be given in next line.

So your code should be.

```
#!/bin/bash
names = find  /home/devuser -name 'BI*'
sqlplus -s  schema_name/passwd << EOF
for name in {names[@]}
do
insert into table1(file_name,status) values('$name','N'); 
done 
commit; 
exit
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's a version of the script that works, and fixes some things you may not have considered:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
(
    echo '-- some startup SQL*plus code'
    echo 'set echo off;'
    echo '-- etc'
    find /home/devuser -name 'BI*' -type f |
    awk -- '{
                gsub("\047", "\047\047", $0);
                printf("INSERT INTO table1(file_name,status) " \
                       "VALUES(\047%s\047, \047N\047);\n", $0);
            }'

    echo 'COMMIT;'
) | sqlplus -s schema_name/passwd
```

Features:

- Selects only files (`-type f` in `find`) matching the glob ‘BI*’ — see the manpage for `find(1)` for the different file types available.
- Escapes filenames containing single quotes ('→'') so the output is valid SQL. `\047` is the octal ASCII code of the single quote, useful since the awk code is inside single quotes already.
- Faster than backtick expansion.
- Leave out the `| sqlplus ...` part of the last line and you can see the SQL script generated.

Limitations:

- Does not work with filenames containing newlines or any other non-printable characters.
- *May* not work with non-ASCII characters. This depends on a number of factors, some on the POSIX side, some on the Oracle side (and some likely inside SQL*plus itself).
- It's not necessarily the best way (better people will no doubt chime in with their versions).

The groupped section in the beginning generates the script, including a prologue (useful for telling SQL*plus what to do with some of its ‘nicer’ features) and an epilogue to commit the transaction.

What's wrong with your own version of the script:

- Assignments are like this: `VAR=foo`. Not `VAR = foo` (yes, it matters; the latter will try to run command `VAR` with arguments `=` and `foo`, not perform a variable assignment)
- If you want `$names` to expand to the results of the `find` command, you need to say `names=$(find ...)` or `` names=`find ...` ``, not `names=find ...`.
- Anything after the `<<EOF` is sent to SQL*Plus, so the bash script fragment you're including (with the `for` loop) is interpreted by SQL*Plus, not bash. That isn't valid SQL, and SQL*Plus naturally chokes on it.
- The body of the `for` loop is an SQL statement, but you're expecting this to be interprered by bash, which isn't right. There should be an `echo` before the SQL `insert` statement (and of course the entire thing out of the `<<EOF` section).
- You've left out the `EOF` itself. `<<EOF` means ‘read until a line is encountered that starts with `EOF`’.